# ArcGIS REST Server Object Extension Examples

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api, server-object-extension

I'm looking for a few good examples of a REST server object extension (SOE) showing more than the common ESRI sample. I'd like to see some RestOperation samples as well and a few different TryGet statements (i.e.. returning integers and strings). Looking at ver 10.2 using SQL.

Answer (score 4):

[This is a template](https://github.com/steveoh/SolarCalculator) that I created and use as a boilerplate for most of my SOE projects.

I hope this helps.